# Bower-Rails Gem Issues Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku, bower, bower-install

I am looking to get a demo of an angular app on Heroku. I am using bower-rails and it runs just fine locally. I have followed this tutorial

https://medium.com/for-the-public-benefit/deploying-rails-bower-on-heroku-3b4ca4908a59

Still getting this error. I have searched my entire code for "‘" with no luck. Please help... It seems to be failing when it starts to precompile the Angular code since that is the next folders in the assets after the modal.

When I run assets precompile locally there is no error.

```
 remote:        I, [2017-03-28T22:56:34.028467 #1285]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/public/assets/Modal/blue-post-1d770bcb3e85d73cf87479de116bb78b07e50e0d35678f2d0cfc4c24d0009f3a.png
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected character '‘'
remote:        JS_Parse_Error.get ((execjs):3538:621)
remote:        (execjs):4060:47
remote:        (execjs):1:102
remote:        Object.<anonymous> ((execjs):1:120)
remote:        Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
remote:        Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
remote:        Module.load (module.js:487:32)
remote:        tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
remote:        Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
remote:        Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in `eval'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-3.1.10/lib/uglifier.rb:190:in `run_uglifyjs'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-3.1.10/lib/uglifier.rb:152:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:53:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_200d7bb55827f631363d75638b763a05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to XXXXXXXX.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/XXXXXXXX.git
```

Comment: More details: so far it looks like a Heroku issue as it has precompiled assets that are no longer part of the application and will not let go.

Comment: solved - branch merger issues.